# Linux "screen" session script

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to write a script to boot up some screen sessions and to "cd" into the home folder. But this is not working as expected. If I use

```
screen -t 'screen-session:tab1'
screen -t 'screen-session:tab2'
screen -t 'screen-session:tab3'
screen -t 'screen-session:tab4'

# This one detaches 
screen -dm bash -c 'cd; cd folder; tail -f error.log'
```

This opens 4 different sessions.

How can I open up one session and then open up tabs and run different init commands per tab?

Comment: Note that the `screen` tag you have attached to your question says (something like) "For questions related to the linux screen utility, use the `gnu-screen` tag. Did you check `man screen` on your system for other options or examples that may help? Good luck.

Comment: thank you very much for that feed back. I'll change that now. And yes I've been playing around with the command for a while and there are a few possibilities but I'm sure I'd be doing it wrong. So i thought it would be better to ask people as I'm not the first to want to do something like this for sure

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020130/how-to-run-a-screen-with-4-tabs-and-different-commands-tunning-in-each) help ?

Comment: (^^^The above looks very promising^^^)(edit) I know these sort of use cases have come up before. Search for `[gnu-screen]` and see all the Q/A that is out there already. You're likely to find something that will help. Good luck.

Comment: Somehow I am unable to edit my above comment. But [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/how-to-open-tabs-windows-in-gnu-screen-execute-commands-within-each-one?noredirect=1#comment108967_74785) it is explained very well and has all you need. I would recommend you to check this one out instead of my previous comment.